# How would I disable accounts that have been inactive for 90 days in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, command, user-accounts

Working on a script that disables accounts that have been inactive for 90 days. Couldn't really find an answer after researching my problem for a few days, but I did find this command on a forum:

```
    lastlog -t 10000 > temp1; lastlog -t 90 > temp2; diff temp1 temp2; rm temp1; rm temp2
```

This command outputs the users that have been inactive for 90 days. I think the solution to my problem would be to:

1. Filter the output of this command so only the usernames are displayed (in a list, with 1 username per line).
2. Take this output and write it to a text file.
3. Run a for-loop that for each line in the file, the contents of the line (which should be just a single username) are stored in a variable called "inactiveUser". Then the command *usermod -L $inactiveUser* will be executed.

Would my proposed solution work? If so, how could it be achieved? Is there a much easier method to lock inactive accounts that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simplify this with:

```
lastlog -b 90
```

which directly lists users who have not logged in in the past 90 days.

however, it also has a header row, and lists lots of system users.

use `tail` to skip the header row:

```
lastlog -b 90 | tail -n+2
```

then you could use `grep` to filter out system users:

```
lastlog -b 90 | tail -n+2 | grep -v 'Never log'
```

although perhaps there is a safer way to find real, non-system users, e.g.:

```
cd /home; find * -maxdepth 0 -type d
```

that issue aside, you can get just the usernames out with `awk`:

```
lastlog -b 90 | tail -n+2 | grep -v 'Never log' | awk '{print $1}'
```

then either output the list to a file, or else directly run `usermod` via `while read` loop or `xargs`:

```
lastlog -b 90 | tail -n+2 | grep -v 'Never log' | awk '{print $1}' |
  xargs -I{} usermod -L {}
```

perhaps you should also log what you've done:

```
lastlog -b 90 | tail -n+2 | grep -v 'Never log' | awk '{print $1}' |
  tee -a ~/usermod-L.log | xargs -I{} usermod -L {}
```

Comment: This works great! Redirected the output into a text file and ran a while-loop to disable all the users. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While the other answer works, it can be made much cleaner by using `awk` instead of `tail | grep | awk`

```
lastlog -b 90 | awk '!/Never log/ {if (NR > 1) print $1}' |  xargs -I{} usermod -L {}
```

The `awk` command checkes for lines that don't have the expression 'Never log' in it (`!/Never log/`).

`NR > 1` emulates `tail -n +2`.

`print $1` prints the first column.

Comment: I tried to write an answer that was comprehensible and educational for beginners, but this answer is more practical, and probably the one I would use.